# Command line arguments for running Orange

Tags: orange

I would like to run Orange data miner (version 2.7) on commandline. Can someone tell me the arguments available to run Orange on commandline ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This post still comes up as the top result on Google.

The correct answer is explained here:
https://github.com/biolab/orange3#starting-orange-gui

> To start Orange GUI from the command line, assuming it was
>   successfully installed, run:
>
> ```
> orange-canvas
> # or
> python3 -m Orange.canvas
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Orange as a Python module, see http://docs.orange.biolab.si/tutorial/rst/index.html.

If not -- what did you mean by running from command line?

Comment: I am trying to connect Orange canvas to another program (Pipeline pilot) that can call it on commandline. The question I have is how do I send a data file to an Orange canvas via the commandline.